# onClick method in fragment never gets called

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I tried to set up a onClickListener inside my fragment.

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

Button btn_eventList;
public HomeFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    btn_eventList = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonEventList);
    btn_eventList.setOnClickListener(this);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    btn_eventList.setText("TEST");
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "TEST" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

}
```

Here is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/nvd"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">



    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="test"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView4"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="test"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonEventList"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Button" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button9"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Button" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button7"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Button" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/lst_nav_drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        >

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Does anyone know why the onClick method never gets called when I hit my button? Did I miss anything?

Comment: You are doing it in a weird way, just do a separate listener class or anonymous listener.

Comment: Can you show us fragment_home layout?

Comment: Also: did you tried to rebuild? are you sure that you are using this fragment? **this code should work.**

Comment: i see no problem with your code......please make sure there is a button with id as buttonEventList  there in your layout(fragment_home)

Comment: As RissmonSuresh says there is nothing wrong with the code. I have just tested your solution and its working. Please post the fragment_home layout like @Selvin suggested and tell us how are you using the Fragment

Comment: Okay here is my layout: http://pastebin.com/raw/Xxdsxwni

Comment: @SaraLince check my answer below, I got the solution to your problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## EDIT

Since Sevin made me notice I was not giving you a solution but an alternative way for reaching your goal, I'm editing this.

**First: your code must work**

The code you posted is correct

**Now, do some checks:**

- Check if in debug mode the button is not null (should have throwed exception)
- Check if in debug mode you are reaching the onClick, even if the text doesn't change and even if the toast doesn't show up.
- Check if you are showing the fragment properly. [Here is the official documentation about how to create a fragment.](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html)
- Check if the fragment is clickable and if it has anything over it (simply, the button once clicked shows the classic "click" animation?)
- Check in the xaml code if the id you used is assigned to the correct button.

**And finally do some the following operations:**

- Clean your project
- Rebuild your project
- Check if in both xaml and java code you have any alert (in basic configurations, yellow mark over the line)
- Uninstall the app and re-install it (pretty much the same, but since we don't know your project, it can still help)

After those, let us know

**Possible solution:**

You have a `recycleview` which is on top of the `button`. you have this view set with `match parent` both height and width inside a `relativelayout`, it means that this view will cover the button.

Remove this empty `recycleview` and the code will work

Comment: How this will help with his real problem which is "onClick method never gets called" ?

Comment: @Selvin because seeing the poor code he gave us, the problem must be in the listener call (I really expect he did something like a debug). Sicne the code he posted must work, checking if this works also will give us an huge hint on where is the real problem. btw this way works, and it's pretty much the same thing so it's a solution

Comment: *it's pretty much the same thing* no, it is not the same... it creates instance of annonymous class unnecessarily ... *so it's a solution* no, it not resolve his main problem

Comment: I'm using the same solution as yours in my projects :) (for the reasons that you wrote -  *distinguish all buttons each others* ) ... but ... it is not an answer to the question ...

Comment: @Selvin yeah, you are right. I radically changed the answer and now it's more like a "debug guide" but i think this is what he needs

Comment: I can't see the  classic "click" animation. Maybe my button is not clickable somehow? I posted my layout file above.

Comment: @SaraLince check the edited answer under "solution" header

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

after posting your layout I can conclude with total certainty that your REcyclerView is taking all the space of your layout thus taking all the touch inputs from whats behind.

**Solutions:**

You can either delete the recycler view or re-arrange it and add it to last RelativeLayout and use `layout_below` and placing it below the a LinearLayout

Comment: How this will help with his real problem which is "onClick method never gets called" ?

Comment: Troubleshooting... then we can keep investigating based on the results (process of elimination)

Comment: [Programming by permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_by_permutation) , no, thanks!

Comment: unfortunately this didn't help

Comment: Thank you that was the problem. I re-arranged it. Btw the code you were suggesting earlier, is that the better way of doing it? If I have your way do I have to remove the 'implements View.OnClickListener' ?

Comment: Its one way, and one of the most common, there are lots. I particularly like this approach because you can manage multiple buttons with ease. Image you have 4 buttons in your layout if you use the listener in the class you'd to implement the solution Pihariev gave which will be not mantainable later on with those cases and code in between

Comment: @SaraLince apart from that you have: data-bindings,  onClick property on xml, with annotations (Butterknife) (the one I use for most projects)

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you didn't implement this method right. `onClick()` method doesn't know, what view concretely has been clicked. Change your onClick() method to the following form:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.your_button_id: 
            btn_eventList.setText("TEST");
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "TEST" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't matter since there is only 1 call of `setOnClickListener(HomeFragment .this)` also how this will help with his real problem which is "onClick method never gets called" ?

Comment: @Selvin, oh, thanks for correction, it's my inattention :)